# File uploading and email in JSP

Tags: email, forms, jsp, attachment

I need to make a simple page in JSP. I've never worked in JSP before ever.

I have a form that has two fields: one is a file upload field and the other is a textbox. The user enters one email address in the field and uploads a file and upon submission. I should be able to email the attachment to the email address entered.

I need a quick code snippet that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to see this [code](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5379129), might need some debugging though :)

or this one from [here](http://www.oop-reserch.com/smtpsender.html) (through the JavaMail API):

```
  SmtpSender smtp=SmtpSender.getInstance();
   MailToBeSent send=new MailToBeSent();
   send.setSubject("Hello");
   send.setFromAddress("some@bar.com","Someone");
   send.addToAddress("another@foo.com","Anotherone");
   send.setBody("Hello, test with the file attachment!");
   byte[] bin=.....
   send.attacheFile(bin,"photo.jpg","image/jpeg");
   smtp.sendMail(send);
```